# What format should the depending variable in a binary logistic regression be? (for R)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

What format should it be? I am talking about a binary logistic regression and my dependent variables are already just 1s and 0s.

```
> str(data$returnShipment)
 int [1:481092] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
```

Is integer correct or what should it be?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is read the help file. From `?glm`:

> A typical predictor has the form `response ~ terms` where `response` is
>   the (numeric) response vector and `terms` is a series of terms which
>   specifies a linear predictor for response.
>
> For `binomial` and `quasibinomial` families the response can also be
>   specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all
>   others success) or as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the
>   numbers of successes and failures.

So it can be numeric 1s and 0s, a factor, or two columns indicating the number of successes and failures at each value of predictors.

Answer (score 2):

The response variable should contain only 0s and 1s (so integer is ok). Also, there must be only a single column of numbers for the response, [in contrast to proportion data where two vectors (successes and failures) were bound together to form the response].

Comment: Why the hate for two-column response? I don't see a reason it wouldn't work here.